# Terminate ajax call while redirecting to another page

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
        beforeSend: function () {
            ...
        },
        complete: function () {
            ...
        }, 
        url: "serviceUrl",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        data: jsonObj,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        statusCode: {
            200 /*Get*/: function (responseData) {
                successCallback(responseData);
            },
            201 /*Created*/: function (responseData) {
                successCallback(responseData);
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            handleException(jqXHR.status, failureCallback);
        }
    });
```

I am using the above ajax call. In IE If I redirect to some other page in between  ajax calling process, It takes long time to load the redirected page which contains another ajax call. Same code show exception (error) in Chrome before redirecting

How to terminate ajax calls while redirecting to another page?

Answer (score 0):

you can abort the ajax call, using the xhr object returned by the ajax function. like this:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: "name=John&location=Boston",
    success: function(msg){
       alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    }
});

//kill the request
xhr.abort()
```

Comment: I wrote a common function to deal with ajax call. So I dont know where to place xhr.abort(). ex:- function ajaxPost(model, serviceUrl, successCallback, failureCallback) {$.ajax({...}}

Comment: @user930453 I don't entirely understand when you wanted to abort. can you elaborate/show all the code?

Comment: I wrote ajax call within function. I ll call that function wherever i need.
Before getting respone, if i redirect to second page(by clicking menu button) it takes time to load the second page which contains ajax call in IE. But in Chrome it goes to ajax error function and loads the page immediately

Comment: what do you mean "before getting response"? where exactly?

Comment: i.e before getting response data(ajax success status code 200)

Comment: but from where are you doing the redirect? what's the code path? why don't you just share the entire code, maybe on jsfiddle

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25506/discussion-between-moshe-shaham-and-user930453)